# Help Proving Limit Doesn't Exist

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck trying to prove that a function has no limit. The limit in question is that the function $$f(x, y) = \frac{x^3 + 2y + \cos(xy)}{y^2x}$$ does not have a limit when $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$. I have tried re-parametrizing $x$ and $y$ such that the limit converges differently for 2 different sets of values, but nothing I have done so far gives anything other than an indeterminate form.

Any help would be much appreciated with this problem. Thanks in advance for anyone's time and help with this problem.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set x=y

$$\frac{x^3 + 2y + \cos(xy)}{y^2x}=\frac{x^3 + 2x + \cos(x^2)}{x^3}=\\=1+\frac{2x + \cos(x^2)}{x^3}\to \pm \infty$$